# Pitfalls with modeling problems as graphs

Tags: graph-theory, set-theory

The motivation for this question is that I could solve problem by extracting a graph structure from it and then applying a standard graph-algorithm and transfering the solution back to the interpretation for the original problem.

But somehow I suspected that there may be situations in which a naïve interpretation of objects as graph-vertices and of relations between pairs of (not necessarily distinct) objects as graph-edges could be flawed.

I finally found an example that could illustrates the reason for my concerns:
Let

- $S=\lbrace 1,2,3,\dotsc,n\rbrace$, $3\le n\lt\infty$
- $\mathcal{P}(S)$ the power set of $S$ and $\mathcal{P}'(S)=\mathcal{P}(S)\setminus\lbrace\emptyset\,\cup \lbrace\lbrace i\rbrace|1\le i\le n\rbrace\,\cup\lbrace S\rbrace\rbrace$

whence a naïve definition for a graph $G(V,E): V=\mathcal{P}'(S),\ E=\lbrace\,\lbrace u,v\rbrace\subset V\times V\,|\  u\cap v\notin \lbrace \emptyset,\,u,\,v\rbrace\,\rbrace$ could aim at modeling  a certain intersection structure.

The problematic issues with that example are:

- different edges in the graph model may refer to the same *object* in the original setting: $\lbrace 1,2,3\rbrace\cap\lbrace 2,3,4\rbrace = \lbrace 2,3,7\rbrace\cap\lbrace 2,3,5\rbrace$
- some *objects* may correspond to vertices and also to edges as a result of intersection.

> **Question:**
>
> under what conditions can a problem be modeled as a graph in a way that there is a bijection between claims related to the original problem and the claim's interpretation in the the problem's graph-abstraction?

Comment: Your question seems to be about when modelling by graphs works *well*, whereas your title seems to be about when it works *poorly*.  But anyway surely any problem can be modelled poorly using any tools, so surely the focus should be on avoiding poor modelling, not on avoiding any paticular tools?

Comment: @LSpice the questioned is aimed at how to safeguard about modeling poorly as graphs; e.g. by checking that different edges in the graph-model actually represent different "entities" of the original problem.